# Subtracting User Input Dates in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-datetime

I'm trying to subtract two user input days. The user would input the start and end date in the format of (YYYYMMDD). So far the code below is what I have but I keep getting a TypeError.

```
import sys, datetime

startDate = sys.argv[1]
endDate = sys.argv[2]

d1 = datetime.date(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
d2 = datetime.date(endDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

print d1, d2
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `date()` incorrectly. See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#date-objects

It wants, 3 integers.  Year, month, day.

```
datetime.date(2020, 11, 9)
```

The error message is telling you that putting the string `"%Y-%m-%d"` in the arguments is not correct.

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```